# specified module could not be found - classic asp

Tags: iis

I'm running out of energy on what appeared to be a fairly straightforward project at first. This project is to move an ASP application from Win2K to a windows xp system. Technology churn apparently is making this endeavor quite a hassle.

Anyway...my latest problem has to to with the blunt but cryptic error

"the specified module could not be found".

What module?

I have found a link which says that if I identify the module, I can use this command:

regsvr32 %systemroot%\System32\xxxx.dll

My question is, how do I identify said dll? I tried looking in the IIS log, but didn't see anything I could be sure of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. It's the most frustrating error message in the world. Surely there must be a log of some kind somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The "specified module not found" error could be because you don't have iissuba.dll in your C:\Windows\ folder. Iissuba is the "subauthentication" module that controls IUSR_machinename's password. You can extract iissuba.dl_ from the CD or folder that you installed IIS from.

Answer (score 0):

Would your site happen to be using CDONTS to send e-mails? CDONTS isn't installed by default on Windows XP - XP has CDO instead.